# Realtime value display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

To perform some 'fade in' effect in the div's with class `subject` I have written the code below (in a .js document):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll( function(){
        $('.subject').each( function(i){
            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object +700){
                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500);                  
            }    
        });    
    });    
});
```

However, I am not very used to `scrollTop()`, so to understand it better, I would like that somehow in the `div` the value of the `scrollTop()` is displayed instantaneously when scrolling (although I will remove it after I have understood `scrollTop()` correctly). **How may this real-time display be accomplished?**

Any suggestion is welcome

Comment: May I suggest an alternative?  You can `console.log` variables and return values of functions, which displays it in your browser's javascript console (Chrome or Firefox preferably).  You can also use `console.dir` to list out the properties of an object, although I don't know how supported it is.  For your case, you could `console.log($(window).scrollTop())` or `console.log(bottom_of_window, bottom_of_object)` in your function to see exactly what it's returning.  [More information from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console)